# Refresh view of sibling component in angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have 2 sibling components, in first one i have form for creating, and in the other one i display results. Both of them are displayed on parent component (dashboard). When i submit data in first component (create new task), on success im calling ngOnInit() function from second component. It is triggered, data is loaded, but for some reason view is not refreshing. Why? Any ideas?

form component smth like this:

```
import { DisplayDataComponent } from '..'

@Component({   
selector: '.....',   
templateUrl: '...',   
styleUrls: ['....'],   
providers: [ DisplayDataComponent ] }) 

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

          constructor(
            private displayComponent: DisplayDataComponent,   ) {

          refreshDisplayComp() {
            this.displayComponent.ngOnInit();  // <--- and its being triggered...
          }



         formSubmitingFunction(data) { 
              this.someservice.submitData(data).subscribe(res => {
                 this.refreshDisplayComp() 
             }, err => {
                 ...
            })
         }
     }
```

COmponent for displaying, smth like this:

```
  @Component({   
    selector: '.....',   
    templateUrl: '...',   
    styleUrls: ['....'],   

    export class DisplayDataComponent implements OnInit {
            data = [];


              constructor(
                ) {

              ngOnInit() {
                  loadData();
              }



             loadData() { 
                  this.someservice.getData().subscribe(res => {
                     this.data = res.data;
                     console.log(this.data) // <--- it shows data is loaded but not displayed?
                 }, err => {
                     ...
                })
             }
         }
```

Html part that displays data

```
<div class="card-body sub-body">
            <div class="event row" *ngFor="let note of data; let i = index"  [attr.data-index]="i">
                <div class="col-md-9"> {{note.note}} </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 icons" *ngIf="note.creatorId == currentUserId">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" (click)="openModal(template1, note, 2)"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" (click)="deleteNote(note.id)"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Logs from that displaying data component: 
[image]
first array is initial ngOnInit() and second one is after successful creation. SO its called, loaded, but not displayed

Comment: Without seeing the markup in your view there is no way for us to help you.

Comment: @AdrianBrand the part for displaying data? added

Comment: Don't worry, I have answered your question below, the problem is not in your view.

Comment: This is not the proper way of implementing communication between components. Try one of the methods described in https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andreas suggested, for some reason this approach didnt work. Confusing why was I even able to trigger function then. I'm guessing it was treated as a service. Anyways, managed to make it work by following instructions in [link](https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb) he left (case 1). I wont copy my code cause its very messy, and I'm short with the time to write dummy one.. but here on this [github link](https://github.com/mkoczka/angular-components-communication/tree/approach-1/src) u have exactly that, so just follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the load data function an arrow function that way you know that this will be your component and not your service.

```
loadData = () => { 
              this.someservice.getData().subscribe(res => {
                 this.data = res.data;
                 console.log(this.data) // <--- it shows data is loaded but not displayed?
             }, err => {
                 ...
            })
         };
```

You need to understand how this is bound with normal functions vs arrow functions.

Comment: Then try putting the contents of loadData into the ngOnInit method.

Comment: still same.. i dont think thats the problem, function is being triggered, data is being loaded, there you can see it in console log that its loaded, but view is not refreshing for some reason... like it doesnt see change in value of data array